# how to catch ethereum contract exception?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

This is my simple contract

```
contract Test {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function Test(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    }

function gettokenBalance(address to)constant returns (uint256){
          return balanceOf[to];
       }
}
```

When i am transferring tokens more than intial supply to another account the function `transfer` should throws exception.

How can i handle this exception and get to know transaction cannot complete.I am using web3j and calling function transfer like

```
Test test = Test.load(contractObj.getContractAddress(), web3j, credentials, gasprice,gaslimit);

TransactionReceipt balanceOf = test.transfer(new Address(address), transferBalance).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i handle this exception and get to know transaction cannot
>   complete

There is a single exception (a `throw` without arguments) in Solidity, which is "out of gas". So your "faulty" transaction **is** completed, however it ran out of gas. If you know the transaction hash, you can check `gasLimit` and `gasUsed`. If they are equal, your transaction has probably`*` ran out of gas. See more information [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e).

`*` given that you supply more than enough gas that a "correct" transaction requires.

Comment: Thanks @jeff , but I have solved this by rather than looking for exception , i have checked the balance of from account first,whether it has sufficient funds or not than do the transaction .

Comment: In that case, most transaction signing libraries will give you an "insufficient funds" error without even sending the transaction. But yes, that's an important check. And I'm glad your problem is solved!

Comment: yeah, actually i am checking the balance of from account before transferring balance to another account .

Answer (score -1):

I have never used web3js but you can try using try-catch:

```
try{
  Test test = Test.load(contractObj.getContractAddress(), web3j, credentials, gasprice,gaslimit);

  TransactionReceipt balanceOf = test.transfer(new Address(address), transferBalance).get(); 
} catch (Exception e){
  // log you exception
}
```